# convert user input to array of Ints in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, int, character

I'm trying to make a simple iOS game to learn programming in swift.
The user inputs a 4 digits number in a text field (keyboard type number pad if that matters) and my program should take that 4 digits number and put each digit in an array.
basically I want something like

```
userInput = "1234"
```

to become

```
inputArray = [1,2,3,4]
```

I know converting a string to an array of characters is very easy in swift

```
var text : String = "BarFoo"
var arrayText = Array(text)
//returns ["B","a","r","F","o","o"]
```

my problem is I need my array to be filled with Integers, not characters.
If I convert the user input to an Int, it becomes a single number so if user enters "1234" the array gets populated by [1234] and not [1,2,3,4]

So I tried to treat the user input as a string, make an array of its characters and, then loop through the elements of that array, convert them to Ints and put them into a second array, like:

```
var input : String = textField.text
var inputArray = Array(input)
var intsArray = [Int]()

for var i = 0; i < inputArray.count ; i++ {
    intsArray[i] = inputArray[i].toInt()
}
```

but it doesn't compile and gives me the error: `'Character' does not have a member named 'toint'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want `1234` instead of `1,2,3,4` then you don't need an array for that. `1234` is a single `int` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
let text : String = "123a"
let digits = Array(text).map { String($0).toInt()! }
// Crash if any character is not int
```

But it will crash if input is not valid.

You can validate by checking the result of `toInt()`:

```
let text : String = "1234"
var digits = Array(text).reduce([Int](), combine: { (var digits, optionalDigit) -> [Int] in
    if let digit = String(optionalDigit).toInt() {
        digits.append(digit)
    }

    return digits
})

if countElements(text) == digits.count {
    // all digits valid
} else {
    // has invalid digits
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first piece of code is enough because the user can only enter integers since I set the text field keyboard type to "Number Pad".

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to get characters from string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler solution for future users

```
let text : String = "12345"
var digits = [Int]()
for element in text.characters 
{
    digits.append(Int(String(element))!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert String into [Int] extension - Swift Version**

I put below extensions which allow you to convert `String` into `[Int]`.
It's long version, where you can see what happen in each line with your string.

```
extension String {

    func convertToIntArray() -> [Int]? {

        var ints = [Int]()
        for char in self.characters {
            if let charInt = char.convertToInt() {
                ints.append(charInt)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        return ints
    }
}


extension Character {

    func convertToInt() -> Int? {
        return Int(String(self)) ?? nil
    }
}
```