# Why do I get the error "Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'sequence'

Tags: iphone, xcode8, swift2

I'm trying to convert user input from a textField to an array.
I followed the code that was offered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501398

```
let someString : String = someTextField.text!
let someArray = Array(someString).map { String($0).toInt()! }
```

But then I get this error:

```
 Argument type "String" does not conform to expected type "Sequence"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me when I substitute a literal for `someTextField.text!`. Can you add a test case?

Comment: @Eric M. Thank you for your help! I'm not sure what you mean by "test case".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that as of Swift 2.0, `String` no longer conforms to `SequenceType`. You can work around this if you're really in love with functional programming. However, there's no need to get so fancy here:

```
let text : String = "12345"
var digits = [Int]()
for element in text.characters {
    digits.append(Int(String(element))!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, your proposal seems to only work for a literal, and not for textField input. I tried your method and substituted "12345" with someTextField.text! and now I get an error at the line "digits.append(element.toInt())" that says "Value of type 'Character' has no member 'toInt'"

Comment: @Theodore.K You'll want to use `Int(element)` instead of `element.toInt()`. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @Theodore.K To expand on that, it seems `.toInt()` etc was also removed in Swift 2.0, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771119/convert-character-to-int-in-swift-2-0)

Comment: Thank you! I tried that, and I got an error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Character)'

Comment: This is what that line currently looks like: digits.append(Int(element))

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** `characters` is deprecated, so above code would be like this:

```
let text : String = "12345"
var digits = [Int]()
for element in text {
    digits.append(Int(String(element))!)
}
```